# why it is needed to update the linux-images in ubuntu

Tags: drivers, kernel

I had recently updated the linux image and kernel files.i found that after doing it,my system resolution becomes like a (without display driver) fonts,icons are big big..so....when entering to that updated generic images..while with the old i found its good and normal...hence why we need to update it the images....
kindly the info of that is 3.5.0-23-generic(old and good display of my monitor)
while new updates is 3.5.0.45-generic(where everything looks big)
so i need to know why its happens and why to update this images

Answer (score 0):

The main reasons to update your packages, the kernel induced are:

1. Security - Updates often patch security holes and the kernel is one of the most important security updates. See http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/
2. Bug fixes. Updates also bring bug fixes
3. New features. The kernel often brings new features and video drives are written for specific kernels.

It is always a good idea to review updates before you apply them.

If you need help with your hardware, identify your video card and if you installed any drivers, how did you do so?

Answer (score 0):

The versions you mention are versions of the Linux kernel, most likely there is some compability issue or some missing configuration between the newer kernel version and whatever drivers you are running.

Are you running 12.10? If so, I'd like to point out that 12.10 goes [out of support in April 2014 (one month from now)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Table_of_versions). You should run either 12.04 which is a LTS release (Long Term Support) or plan an update to 14.04 which is the next LTS planned for release this April. Quite likely, your display problems will be resolved in this newer version.

If you were to mention what GPU you have, it would be easier to find examples of drivers and strategies you could try out.